# Windows 7 service pack 1 error

Tags: windows-7, service-pack

When I try and install Windows 7 service pack 1, I get an error that halts the install (code 80073701).

I've looked around quite a bit, and a lot of places say that a language pack may be the culprit, and suggested running lpksetup.exe and seeing if there were any (corrupted) installed language packs. I ran this and it appears my English language (default) pack is corrupt.

[image]

Is this most likely the issue, and if so, is there a way to go about reinstalling the language pack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days of searching for a solution (and not finding one), I decided saving all my stuff to an external hard drive and reformatting was the best way to go.

I reformatted and the first thing I did was install SP 1 (which worked).

If you have an external hard drive and either an installation disk or a recovery partition on your computer, I would suggest just reformatting. It will most likely take much less time than diagnosing the issue and determining how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe your language pack is corrupt. I setup a Windows 7 RTM machine (no SP1), and ran lpksetup. The window was the same as your screen shot. I cancelled out and was able to install SP1. I think lpksetup is just warning you that you only have one language pack, so maybe you don't want to remove it.

1. Try the [System Update Readiness Tool](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/What-is-the-System-Update-Readiness-Tool).
2. Run System File Checker. Open a command prompt, and type `sfc /scannow`.
3. Check C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log for ERROR_SXS_ASSEMBLY_MISSING messages. That may lead you to an update that is missing something. Uninstall these updates, reboot, and try the Service Pack again.

Comment: It seems to reference the error code I gave where ever ERROR_SXS_ASSEMBLY_MISSING pops up: HRESULT = 0x80073701. The only place I see an update number referenced, it's the service pack 1 update itself (KB976932).

Comment: I posted additional things to try (#1 and #2).

Comment: I have unfortunately already run both of those without an issue.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! It is helpful advice, it just didn't fix my specific issue. :-/ I just went ahead and reformatted.